# Is it possible to map two objects from same requestBody in spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I know that we can map an object using `_method(@RequestBody ObjectClass obj)`.

What i'm trying to achieve is `_method(@RequestBody ObjectClass obj, @RequestBody OtherObjectClass obj2)` but doesn't work.

Is there some way to map two objects using same request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A HTTP request is made up of headers and body. 
For a single request, you have a single request body, you can't have two. You can then parse the request body to extract different variables from it, for example if your request body is a JSON, then you can parse it and convert it into an object.

See [this example](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/014-post-json-to-spring-rest-webservice/), further on at section "Passing multiple json objects"